# Spring Cloud Stream From Kafka to RabbitMQ dynamic queues

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I'd like to use Spring Cloud Stream in this pipeline:

- reading incoming messages from Kafka topic (or topics);
- getting from incoming message the particular parameters;
- and that parameters is going to be a routing key for RabbitMQ queue.

In other words, I'd like to route messages from Kafka to different RabbitMQ queues using parameters from incoming messages.
I've tried to use RabbitMQ exchange with type headers. But I got the error below and messages had saved in all queues - the headers had been ignored

```
"Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'type' for exchange 'upstream.ecom' in vhost '/': received 'topic' but current is 'headers', class-id=40, method-id=10)"
```

This is my application.yaml

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev
  kafka:
    jaas:
      enabled: true
    properties:
      security:
        protocol: "SASL_PLAINTEXT"
      sasl:
        mechanism: PLAIN
        jaas:
          config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="client" password="client-secret";
  cloud:
    stream:
      default-binder: rabbit
      function:
        definition: upstreamProcessor
      bindings:
        upstreamProcessor-in-0:
          destination: upstream.ecom
          group: ms-upstream-provider
          binder: kafka
        upstreamProcessor-out-0:
          destination: upstream.ecom
          binder: rabbit
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder.applicationId: ms-upstream-provider-dev
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:19093, localhost:29093, localhost:39093
        bindings:
          upstreamProcessor-in-0:
            consumer:
              configuration:
                key.deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
                spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
                value.deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
                spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      binders:
        rabbit:
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                host: localhost
                port: 5672
                username: client
                password: client-secret
                virtual-host: /
        kafka:
          type: kafka
```

And here my function

```
@Bean
public Function<String, Message<String>> upstreamProcessor() {

    return value -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(value)
            .setHeader("x-destination", "34-0029-1/34-0029-1_DB")
            .setHeader("x-type", "upstream.ecom")
            .build();
}
```

Regarding RabbitMQ exchange and queue binding settings this message ought to be routed to the "34-0029-1/34-0029-1_DB.ecom" queue. But it was routed to all queues :(

May be I shouldn't have used headers routing but I don't understand how to emit to the particular queue from function using dynamic routing key.

Can you give a clue what is wrong with my code or may be you have an example RabbitMQ dynamic routing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all

> received 'topic' but current is 'headers'

By default, SCSt creates topic exchanges, your existing exchange is a headers exchange. You need to set the `exchange-type` or `declare-exchange` consumer property https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties

> **exchangeType**

> The exchange type: direct, fanout, headers or topic for non-partitioned destinations and direct, headers or topic for partitioned destinations.

> Default: topic.

> **declareExchange**

> Whether to declare the exchange for the destination.

> Default: true.

Comment: Thank you, Gary!
I've added this settings to producer and it works now